# S3 Presigned URLs: Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed success_action_status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to issue pre-signed URLs over my server and then upload over javascript in the browser. Everything works when I leave out the :success_action_status field but I want to set it to 201 to get back the XML after uploading.

On the Server:

```
s3_bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(UploadFile::DECK_BUCKET)
presigned_url = s3_bucket.presigned_post(
  :key => @upload_file.key,
  :content_length_range => 1..(10*1024),
  :success_action_status => '201',
  :signature_expiration => expire
)

data = { url: presigned_url.url, url_fields: presigned_url.fields }
render json: data, status: :ok
```

On the client:

```
this.file.change(function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("key", that.fields.key);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Credential", that.fields['x-amz-credential']);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
  formData.append("X-Amz-Date", that.fields['x-amz-date']);
  formData.append("Policy", that.fields.policy);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Signature", that.fields['x-amz-signature']);
  formData.append("file", that.file[0].files[0]);
  formData.append("success_action_status", that.fields['success_action_status']);
  that.$http.post(that.url, formData).then(function(response) {
    console.log("yup")
    console.log(response)
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("nope")
    console.log(response)
  });
```

Again it works when I leave off the `success_action_status` field in `presigned_post`. But when I do not I get:

```
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$success_action_status", "201"]
```

Anyone know what's going on?? Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

`formData.append("file", that.file[0].files[0]);` must be the **last** thing appended to the form.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be anything specific in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) as to why this wouldn't work.

#### Update

Try putting `success_action_status` field before the file field

```
this.file.change(function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("key", that.fields.key);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Credential", that.fields['x-amz-credential']);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
  formData.append("X-Amz-Date", that.fields['x-amz-date']);
  formData.append("Policy", that.fields.policy);
  formData.append("X-Amz-Signature", that.fields['x-amz-signature']);
  formData.append("success_action_status", that.fields['success_action_status']);
  formData.append("file", that.file[0].files[0]);
  that.$http.post(that.url, formData).then(function(response) {
    console.log("yup")
    console.log(response)
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("nope")
    console.log(response)
  });
```

Comment: The reason it wouldn't work is exactly because `formData.append("success_action_status",...` is missing.  The policy specifies and constrains what the form must contain, so without this, the form is indeed "invalid according to policy."

Comment: I added `formData.append("success_action_status", '201')` and still the same error. I tried 201 in integer and string form. If I use 201 as an integer in the ruby code then I get an error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can you offer some advice here?

Comment: @frausto `formData.append("file", ...` must be the **last** thing appended to the form.  Add success_action_status above that, not below.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that was it! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @frausto this answer has been updated previously to reflect the correct order. Glad it worked. If this is the accepted answer, marking it as so may be helpful for others.